# CUDA populate small array with contents of larger array

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, reduce

I'm fairly new to CUDA programming, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

In CUDA, I'm trying to populate a small device array B (~20000 `int` elements) with the contents of a large device array A (~20 million `int` elements). A contains mostly zeros, but has about ~20000 non-zero elements, located at random and unknown positions in the array. I'd like to fill B with the non-zero contents of A using CUDA. The order of the elements within B is not important.

I've looked at the SDK and I found a number of "reduce" strategies for, e.g., parallel summing of an array, but each of these approaches reduce the array to a scalar, whereas I'm trying to "reduce" an array to a smaller array. Searching online hasn't yielded anything either. I'm not looking for full code, but just some ideas/links of how to implement this. I'm using C, and if possible, I'd like to do this without using any C++ classes or structures.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're describing sometimes goes by the name **stream compaction**

[Thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) (e.g. `copy_if`) and

[cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___device_module.html) (e.g. `DeviceSelect`) offer options that should have relatively good performance.

If you did want to implement it yourself, stream compaction may use a sequence of lower-level parallel operations, a key one being a prefix sum.  You can get an idea of the build-up of a simple parallel prefix sum (and stream compaction) in [GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).  I'm just adding this for informational purposes; I'm not suggesting you implement either stream compaction or a prefix sum yourself.

A complete stream compaction example using the GPU Gems prefix sum method is [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-put-specific-elements-from-one-array-to-another-array-use-cuda/232010/5).  *However, I strongly encourage anyone to use thrust or cub, instead.*

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for: some terms for future Googling, and a few links to get me started.